# System recovery: can’t manipulate encrypted files

Tags: command-line, encryption, disk-usage, ecryptfs, recovery-mode

Something has used up all the disk space on my home directory and caused my computer to freeze up.  I tried to reboot and the system would not do so, and I then booted into recovery mode.

Using the [instructions on this site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Recovering_Your_Data_Manually) I manually mounted the encrypted home directory to `/home/user/Private`.  Now I am attempting to delete any non critical files and free up space.

When I try to use the rm command on anything in this folder, be it `rm -i *.mp3` I get the error `cannot remove ‘file name.mp3’: no such file or directory` .

I have an external HD and figured I could zip an archive of stuff to keep and put it there, then delete the /home/user folder.  However, if I attempt to get into a folder listed in `/home/user/Private`like `cd Desktop` , cd gives the same error as rm.  I used the command `mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt`.  Now at /mnt/ I can see files from the external hard drive.  Attempting to copy a file to this location also results in failure; e.g.: `root@home:/home/user/Private#  cp foo.doc /mnt/` returns a similar error: `cp:cannot stat ‘foo.doc’: No such file or directory`

I can only see the first level of my home directory, mounted to `/home/user/Private` however I can’t access the sub folders or manipulate the files displayed.  I need to pare down this encrypted folder and cannot do so.  I have root access in recovery mode but the computer does not seem to have the resources necessary to boot up normally and will hang up when this is attempted.  `DF -h` Shows that 100% of the disk usage is /home/user.  I don’t even know what it could be, but that’s a minor issue at this point.

I have subsequently booted to a live install usb and was unsuccessful in my attempt to mount ecryptfs following the [livecd recovery guide.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EncryptedPrivateDirectory#Long_way)
I got the following error: `error mounting ecryptfs: [-2] No such file or directory` 
I then tied to recover the data with `sudo ecryptfs-recover-private`.  It worked! `Private data mounted at [/tmp/ecryptfs.nyF...kl]`
Now there’s one small detail; I can’t access that folder, I can’t chmod it, and I just keep getting “Permission denied” if I try to access it.  It also seems to only be 4.0k.

Looking st the system log allowed me to discover that the latest error,  `error mounting ecryptfs: [-2] No such file or directory` . Was a result of using the simulink.  Upon execution of `sudo mount -t ecryptfs /media/xubuntu/1771....b56/home/.ecryptfs/user/.Private /home/user/Private`  the terminal replied `mounted ecryptfs` .

Thinking the saga over, I `cd /home/user/Private, ls`
And it’s empty!

Comment: `rm -i *.mp3` will only remove files in the current directory, you have to `cd` to the directory which contains the `.mp3`-files first, or specify the path in the command.

Comment: I can see a number of files that meet this description in the directory from which the command is executed.  Even if I select a specific file by name, using tab to complete it, it fails to do so and returns the same error.  Ex: using ‘ls’ I see ‘foo.mp3’ in the folder.  Upon executing  ‘#rm foo.mp3’, I get the error.

Comment: I haven’t even gone ahead with rm -r yet as I can’t execute the operations on a single definite target file.  Could this be due to the way the encrypted file system is mounted and some simulink wizardry?  Chmod required?

Comment: How can `cp foo.doc /mnt/` return the error `cp:cannot stat ‘foo.jpg`, this are different file names. Remind that we are not in front of your screen and cannot see what you see unless you show us original terminal output. I suggest to boot from your installer (Try without installing), then mount your enrypted drive there and examine the problem using the filemanager, that's probably less confusing and more convenient as you have a GUI.

Comment: Ah my mistake, the filenames in this case are arbitrary, so please read both commands referencing foo.doc.  I’ll try to boot from a live image and clean things up that way.